# Squealing brakes, but only on an incline while in reverse - 2012 Suzuki SX4

Tags: brakes, suzuki, brake-calipers

My brakes squeal, but only while I'm reversing down a hill. The brake pads are new. What else could be the cause of this sound?

This is a 2012 Suzuki SX4.

Comment: Does this happen only after the car has been sitting for awhile, such as overnight?

Comment: Most times, yeah. But there are times when it will happen even if the car hasn't been idle for long. What do you think may be the root cause?

Answer (score 1):

Since it happens primarily after your car has been sitting idle for a while, I suspect the brake rotors are getting  a light coating of rust on them due to exposure to the elements.  The first time you apply your brakes the brake pads will remove the rust from the rotors. This is common and nothing to worry about. But not all brakes will squeak.  My daughter's Fiat 500 sits in the same garage as my Chevy truck.  When she backs out of the garage in the morning her brakes squeak - every time.  When I back my truck out of the same garage having sat overnight my brakes don't make any noise.

Comment: Okay, that seems plausible. However, if rust is not the reason, then what else would you say could be the possible reason?

Comment: The next thing I would look at is making sure the anti-rattle clips are not rubbing against the rotor.  The anti-rattle clips can sometimes slip off their mounting brackets due to rust buildup.  Another possibility would be to check the dust shield is not rubbing against the rotor.  Since you said the pads are new did you break-in (called bedding) your new pads? if not that might be a source of the squeal as well.

Comment: If the noise is happening on only one of the four corners of the car the first two options are a more likely cause.  If the noise is happening on multiple corners of the car (fronts, rears, all four corners)  especially where you had new brake pads installed the last option is the more likely cause.